# What is the best practice for free space for a SQL server database drive?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to determine the best practice for sizing a single database on a 120Gb data drive that will contain the LDF and MDF files.

I'm assuming that I don't want to set the size to be the maximum size of the drive, allowing room for moving and reorganising the data. I don't want to let it expand automatically either.

I'd like to set the size to something sensible and clear out the data regularly.

Can anyone provide any guidance?

**EDIT:**

some additional data...

The database is set to "Simple mode" and the transaction logs will be on the same drive as the data files.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to determine the best practice for sizing a single database on a 120Gb data drive that will contain the LDF and MDF files.

Best practice for sizing is always to do capacity planning - how fast does your data grow now?  How fast will it grow in the next 1-5 years?

Add on some contingency, too.

Set your data file large enough to accomodate that now, and put a calendar entry on your calendar to revisit your capacity planning annually (and check your RAID controller for a bad battery or a bad drive, too).

Set your T-log file likewise, but first read [Kimberly Tripp's Transaction Log VLFs – too many or too few?](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/transaction-log-vlfs-too-many-or-too-few/) article.

Then read [Database File Initialization](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175935%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), particularly the Instant File Initialization section and the Group Policy Perform Volume Maintenance requirement.

Note that index maintenance can use up a lot of space in the log.

Then you can set autogrow on both to fixed increments of reasonable size based on how long you can afford to wait for the growth, as well as keeping VLF sizes in check.

Now set a calendar entry or automated process to check on free space regularly - weekly or monthly, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Do not disable autogrow feature. It will break your production environment when transaction log gets too big. Instead make regular full backups, and monitor transaction log size, if it gets too big its a sign that backups are not frequent enough.

Try to avoid shrinking db files in production environment without a very good reason.

Estimate data size increase, without it every arbitral db size is just lottery. Include often ommited features: audit logs, login history, emails/files saved to db.

Instead of setting fixed perfect size plan for db size change based on current needs.

Comment: I will allow auto grow but I'm thinking of sizing the database to about 80% of the drive and then triggering a data cleardown process once it reaches say 75%.

Comment: Usual suspects in db size growth are: transaction logs, audit/log tables, history/changelog tables. Transaction logs can be kept at bay with frequent backups. Everything else requires analysis. I would recommend daily cleanup of audit/historic data older than day/week/month (depending on needs). Starting cleanup when db is bloated can create a lot of problems (transaction log overflow, timeouts, ghost records). Its much more manageable as ongoing process than one time action.

Comment: I completely agree that cleaning up a small amount of data is best but the customer wants to keep the data as long as possible and my current task is to determine the theoretical limits for that. There are far to many variables for my liking hence wanting to know what the best practice is.

Comment: Best practice, in this case, depends on data retention policies.  If those are clearly defined then you can calculate from your existing data and data growth whether you can meet the goals.  If you calculate that you cannot, then management needs to make choices such as (1) reduce retention or (2) increase storage size.

Comment: For a Simple recovery model database, backups have nearly nothing to do with transaction log size.  For a Full recovery model database, Full backups DO NOT set VLFs in the transaction log to unused status.  Only transaction log backups do that!